# A painful bug - LoadInst error in codegen.cpp

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, llvm, backend, llvm-ir

Recently, I've been trying to create a toy language based on an old [tutorial](https://gnuu.org/2009/09/18/writing-your-own-toy-compiler/). I had this idea almost half a year ago, but I don't have the time to do it until now. Anyway, when I'm following the tutorial, I modified the source code to get rid of a handful of compile errors (I believe that most of the errors are related to backward compatibility), but I'm stuck with feeding the "custom-defined code" to the parser.

The error:

```
eric@pop-os:~/Desktop/my_toy_compiler-master$ echo 'int do_math(int a){ int x = a * 5 + 3 } do_math(10)' | ./parser
0x55a3e10a7580
Generating code...
Generating code for 20NFunctionDeclaration
Creating variable declaration int a
Generating code for 20NVariableDeclaration
Creating variable declaration int x
Creating assignment for x
Creating binary operation 274
Creating integer: 3
Creating binary operation 276
Creating integer: 5
Creating identifier reference: a
parser: /home/eric/llvm-project/llvm/lib/IR/DataLayout.cpp:740: llvm::Align llvm::DataLayout::getAlignment(llvm::Type*, bool) const: Assertion `Ty->isSized() && "Cannot getTypeInfo() on a type that is unsized!"' failed.
Aborted (core dumped)
```

The problem starts after 'Creating identifier reference: a'. Therefore, it is intuitive to take a look at the relevant code. There are two functions in the `codegen.cpp` that are considered significant to this bug.

excerpt of `codegen.cpp`:

```
...

static Type *typeOf(const NIdentifier& type) 
{
    if (type.name.compare("int") == 0) {
        return Type::getInt64Ty(MyContext);
    }
    else if (type.name.compare("double") == 0) {
        return Type::getDoubleTy(MyContext);
    }
    return Type::getVoidTy(MyContext);
}

...

Value* NIdentifier::codeGen(CodeGenContext& context)
{
    std::cout << "Creating identifier reference: " << name << endl;
    
    if (context.locals().find(name) == context.locals().end()) {
        std::cerr << "undeclared variable " << name << endl;
        return NULL;
    }
    return new LoadInst(typeOf(name), context.locals()[name], "", false, context.currentBlock());
}

...
```

The full version of `codegen.cpp`:

```
#include "node.h"
#include "codegen.h"
#include "parser.hpp"

using namespace std;

/* Compile the AST into a module */
void CodeGenContext::generateCode(NBlock& root)
{
    std::cout << "Generating code...\n";
    
    /* Create the top level interpreter function to call as entry */
    vector<Type*> argTypes;
    FunctionType *ftype = FunctionType::get(Type::getVoidTy(MyContext), makeArrayRef(argTypes), false);
    mainFunction = Function::Create(ftype, GlobalValue::InternalLinkage, "main", module);
    BasicBlock *bblock = BasicBlock::Create(MyContext, "entry", mainFunction, 0);
    
    /* Push a new variable/block context */
    pushBlock(bblock);
    root.codeGen(*this); /* emit bytecode for the toplevel block */
    ReturnInst::Create(MyContext, bblock);
    popBlock();
    
    /* Print the bytecode in a human-readable format 
       to see if our program compiled properly
     */
    std::cout << "Code is generated.\n";
    // module->dump();

    legacy::PassManager pm;
    pm.add(createPrintModulePass(outs()));
    pm.run(*module);
}

/* Executes the AST by running the main function */
GenericValue CodeGenContext::runCode() {
    std::cout << "Running code...\n";
    ExecutionEngine *ee = EngineBuilder( unique_ptr<Module>(module) ).create();
    ee->finalizeObject();
    vector<GenericValue> noargs;
    GenericValue v = ee->runFunction(mainFunction, noargs);
    std::cout << "Code was run.\n";
    return v;
}

/* Returns an LLVM type based on the identifier */
static Type *typeOf(const NIdentifier& type) 
{
    if (type.name.compare("int") == 0) {
        return Type::getInt64Ty(MyContext);
    }
    else if (type.name.compare("double") == 0) {
        return Type::getDoubleTy(MyContext);
    }
    return Type::getVoidTy(MyContext);
}

/* -- Code Generation -- */

Value* NInteger::codeGen(CodeGenContext& context)
{
    std::cout << "Creating integer: " << value << endl;
    return ConstantInt::get(Type::getInt64Ty(MyContext), value, true);
}

Value* NDouble::codeGen(CodeGenContext& context)
{
    std::cout << "Creating double: " << value << endl;
    return ConstantFP::get(Type::getDoubleTy(MyContext), value);
}

Value* NIdentifier::codeGen(CodeGenContext& context)
{
    std::cout << "Creating identifier reference: " << name << endl;
    
    if (context.locals().find(name) == context.locals().end()) {
        std::cerr << "undeclared variable " << name << endl;
        return NULL;
    }
    return new LoadInst(Type::getInt64Ty(MyContext), context.locals()[name], "", false, context.currentBlock());
}

Value* NMethodCall::codeGen(CodeGenContext& context)
{
    Function *function = context.module->getFunction(id.name.c_str());
    if (function == NULL) {
        std::cerr << "no such function " << id.name << endl;
    }
    std::vector<Value*> args;
    ExpressionList::const_iterator it;
    for (it = arguments.begin(); it != arguments.end(); it++) {
        args.push_back((**it).codeGen(context));
    }
    CallInst *call = CallInst::Create(function, makeArrayRef(args), "", context.currentBlock());
    std::cout << "Creating method call: " << id.name << endl;
    return call;
}

Value* NBinaryOperator::codeGen(CodeGenContext& context)
{
    std::cout << "Creating binary operation " << op << endl;
    Instruction::BinaryOps instr;
    switch (op) {
        case TPLUS:     instr = Instruction::Add; goto math;
        case TMINUS:    instr = Instruction::Sub; goto math;
        case TMUL:      instr = Instruction::Mul; goto math;
        case TDIV:      instr = Instruction::SDiv; goto math;
                
        /* TODO comparison */
    }

    return NULL;
math:
    return BinaryOperator::Create(instr, lhs.codeGen(context), 
        rhs.codeGen(context), "", context.currentBlock());
}

Value* NAssignment::codeGen(CodeGenContext& context)
{
    std::cout << "Creating assignment for " << lhs.name << endl;
    if (context.locals().find(lhs.name) == context.locals().end()) {
        std::cerr << "undeclared variable " << lhs.name << endl;
        return NULL;
    }
    return new StoreInst(rhs.codeGen(context), context.locals()[lhs.name], false, context.currentBlock());
}

Value* NBlock::codeGen(CodeGenContext& context)
{
    StatementList::const_iterator it;
    Value *last = NULL;
    for (it = statements.begin(); it != statements.end(); it++) {
        std::cout << "Generating code for " << typeid(**it).name() << endl;
        last = (**it).codeGen(context);
    }
    std::cout << "Creating block" << endl;
    return last;
}

Value* NExpressionStatement::codeGen(CodeGenContext& context)
{
    std::cout << "Generating code for " << typeid(expression).name() << endl;
    return expression.codeGen(context);
}

Value* NReturnStatement::codeGen(CodeGenContext& context)
{
    std::cout << "Generating return code for " << typeid(expression).name() << endl;
    Value *returnValue = expression.codeGen(context);
    context.setCurrentReturnValue(returnValue);
    return returnValue;
}

Value* NVariableDeclaration::codeGen(CodeGenContext& context)
{
    std::cout << "Creating variable declaration " << type.name << " " << id.name << endl;
    AllocaInst *alloc = new AllocaInst(typeOf(type), NULL, id.name.c_str(), context.currentBlock());
    context.locals()[id.name] = alloc;
    if (assignmentExpr != NULL) {
        NAssignment assn(id, *assignmentExpr);
        assn.codeGen(context);
    }
    return alloc;
}

Value* NExternDeclaration::codeGen(CodeGenContext& context)
{
    vector<Type*> argTypes;
    VariableList::const_iterator it;
    for (it = arguments.begin(); it != arguments.end(); it++) {
        argTypes.push_back(typeOf((**it).type));
    }
    FunctionType *ftype = FunctionType::get(typeOf(type), makeArrayRef(argTypes), false);
    Function *function = Function::Create(ftype, GlobalValue::ExternalLinkage, id.name.c_str(), context.module);
    return function;
}

Value* NFunctionDeclaration::codeGen(CodeGenContext& context)
{
    vector<Type*> argTypes;
    VariableList::const_iterator it;
    for (it = arguments.begin(); it != arguments.end(); it++) {
        argTypes.push_back(typeOf((**it).type));
    }
    FunctionType *ftype = FunctionType::get(typeOf(type), makeArrayRef(argTypes), false);
    Function *function = Function::Create(ftype, GlobalValue::InternalLinkage, id.name.c_str(), context.module);
    BasicBlock *bblock = BasicBlock::Create(MyContext, "entry", function, 0);

    context.pushBlock(bblock);

    Function::arg_iterator argsValues = function->arg_begin();
    Value* argumentValue;

    for (it = arguments.begin(); it != arguments.end(); it++) {
        (**it).codeGen(context);
        
        argumentValue = &*argsValues++;
        argumentValue->setName((*it)->id.name.c_str());
        StoreInst *inst = new StoreInst(argumentValue, context.locals()[(*it)->id.name], false, bblock);
    }
    
    block.codeGen(context);
    ReturnInst::Create(MyContext, context.getCurrentReturnValue(), bblock);

    context.popBlock();
    std::cout << "Creating function: " << id.name << endl;
    return function;
}
```

Note that there are originally only 3 parameters for the LoadInst function. I checked the [llvm::LoadInst Class Reference](https://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1LoadInst.html) only to see that the LoadInst function now requires at least 4 parameters. I figured out that I (and the author) missed the `Type *Ty` parameter. Obviously, `typeOf(name)` in `return new LoadInst(typeOf(name), context.locals()[name], "", false, context.currentBlock());` is not a solution since `name`, which is `'a'` according to the error, will always make `typeOf(name)` void. I suspect that this causes `Cannot getTypeInfo() on a type that is unsized!`, as stated by the error.

To be short, I believe that I should look for something like this:

```
 Value* NIdentifier::codeGen(CodeGenContext& context)
{
    std::cout << "Creating identifier reference: " << name << endl;

    if (context.locals().find(name) == context.locals().end()) {
        std::cerr << "undeclared variable " << name << endl;
        return NULL;
    }
    return new LoadInst(*some magic that return the llvm::type of name identifier*, context.locals()[name], "", false, context.currentBlock());
}
```

I'm still a noob in llvm, so excuse me if my guess isn't correct. Big thanks for any tips or ideas.

P.S. I tried `return new LoadInst(Type::getInt64Ty(MyContext), context.locals()[name], "", false, context.currentBlock());`. The terminal broke my heart again by saying the follow:

```
eric@pop-os:~/Desktop/my_toy_compiler-master$ echo 'int do_math(int a){ int x = a * 5 + 3 } do_math(10)' | ./parser
0x562120785580
Generating code...
Generating code for 20NFunctionDeclaration
Creating variable declaration int a
Generating code for 20NVariableDeclaration
Creating variable declaration int x
Creating assignment for x
Creating binary operation 274
Creating integer: 3
Creating binary operation 276
Creating integer: 5
Creating identifier reference: a
Creating block
Creating function: do_math
Generating code for 20NExpressionStatement
Generating code for 11NMethodCall
Creating integer: 10
Creating method call: do_math
Creating block
Code is generated.
; ModuleID = 'main'
source_filename = "main"

@.str = private constant [4 x i8] c"%d\0A\00"

declare i32 @printf(i8*, ...)

define internal void @echo(i64 %toPrint) {
entry:
  %0 = call i32 (i8*, ...) @printf(i8* getelementptr inbounds ([4 x i8], [4 x i8]* @.str, i32 0, i32 0), i64 %toPrint)
  ret void
}

define internal void @main() {
entry:
  %0 = call i64 @do_math(i64 10)
  ret void
}

define internal i64 @do_math(i64 %a1) {
entry:
  %a = alloca i64, align 8
  store i64 %a1, i64* %a, align 4
  %x = alloca i64, align 8
  %0 = load i64, i64* %a, align 4
  %1 = mul i64 %0, 5
  %2 = add i64 %1, 3
  store i64 %2, i64* %x, align 4
  ret void
}
Running code...
Function context does not match Module context!
void (i64)* @echo
in function echo
LLVM ERROR: Broken function found, compilation aborted!
Aborted (core dumped)
```

It's sad that my core is dumped anyway.

Comment: `context.locals()[name]->getType()`?

Comment: I tried it. But it returns exactly the same output as the error when I'm using typeOf(name) after the compilation.

Comment: @arrowd Hold on. There is a difference. After `Creating identifier reference: a`, the parser says `parser: /home/eric/llvm-project/llvm/lib/IR/Instructions.cpp:1421: llvm::LoadInst::LoadInst(llvm::Type*, llvm::Value*, const llvm::Twine&, bool, llvm::Align, llvm::AtomicOrdering, llvm::SyncScope::ID, llvm::BasicBlock*): Assertion `\`Ty == cast<PointerType>(Ptr->getType())->getElementType()' failed.\`` before dumping my core. I'll try to figure out what happened.

Comment: Could you show how you construct the `module instance`. I'm guessing that will be in the constructor of the `CodeGenContext` class.

Comment: @droptop Yeah. The code for the `CodeGenContext` class is the same as https://github.com/lsegal/my_toy_compiler/blob/master/codegen.h, where I clone the project. I didn't really dig deep into these codes since they don't trigger compiling errors, could have missed something here.

Comment: In the constructor for `LoadInst` the first argument should be `context.locals()[name]->getType()->getPointerElementType()` since you store pointers or values of type `AllocaInst` in your symbol table.

Comment: Concerning your broken function error, your compiler is reading pass the string that holds your test program.

Comment: @droptop Holy cow it works! Thanks, man. It still shows the broken function error, but I should be able to find a way to fix it.